# Check if ArrayList has a certain index

Tags: vb.net, indexing, arraylist

How do I check if a certain ArrayList index exists?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by an index "existing".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "exists".

If you mean "If the ArrayList *has an index that high*", then you need to look at the `Count`:

```
If arrayList.Count > yourIndex Then
    ...
End If
```

If you mean "Does the ArrayList *have a value at that index*", just check for a null value:

```
If arrayList(yourIndex) Is Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: Can I check in a 2d array for inner values such as i(2)? `sArray = Array(Array("01probe", dbInteger), _
     Array("02datum", dbDate), _
     Array("03bodenart", dbText, 100, True) _
     )`